# How Do I implement PhantomJS + Wedriver on c#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have written the following code and downloaded PhantomJS intot he specified folder on c:\ but am getting the error: "Unable to connect to remote server ...". Here is the code I wrote:

```
[TestMethod]
public void HeadlessBrowser()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver("C:\\trashStuff\\phantomjs-1.9.0-windows"); //or some other driver
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://yahoo.com");

    // Lets take a screenshot to really make sure we did visit the site above
    Console.WriteLine("Take A screen shot");
    Screenshot myScreenShot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
    myScreenShot.SaveAsFile("c:\\trashStuff\\screenshot.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);


    // after the run, go to the location above and find screenshot.jpg
}
```

Comment: same for me. could you give us more details ?

Comment: The above code works ok. The test was timing out. I added the following code and it worked: driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15000));

Answer (score 1):

Download PhantomJS or add it to your project using `NuGet Package Manager`. I got it using `NuGet` and didn't have to put the path to the driver as one of the parameters in `PhantomJSDriver` class.

```
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```